# Automatically link wiki pages

Tags: 2013, wiki, hyperlink

Is it possible to automatically create links to existing wiki pages?

As example: If I have a wiki page called "qwerty" and another page contains somewhere the word "qwerty", this "qwerty" is automatically created with the specific link.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to create links in SharePoint wiki pages is enclose the word you want to turn into a link in double square brackets.

So:
if you type in [[qwerty]] a page named qwerty will be created.
if the page 'qwerty' already exists and you type [[qwerty]] then it will automatically turn the qwerty into a link.

Comment: That's right, but this solution is a little laborious. And at some point you can't handle/remember all existing pages.

Comment: So you want to develop a solution that recognizes every word that you type as you enter it and checks it against your list of wiki pages to see if a page for that term exists and then automatically encloses the term in square brackets to turn it into a link. Yes that's possible.

Comment: Exactly. So.. can you give a hint how to implement this?

Comment: Probably JQuery.